# What do you call this kind of data structure?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

For example, I have this array

```
array[]
array[1] = person1
array[2] = person2
array[3] = person3
```

person2 decides to leave the array

```
array[]
array[1] = person1
array[2] = nil
array[3] = person3
```

person4 comes in and finds index 2 empty, so he seizes that index (without shifting/rearranging the array)

```
array[]
array[1] = person1
array[2] = person4
array[3] = person3
```

pretty bad explanation but hope you got the idea. :-)

Comment: Sounds like a finite set of bounded size with arbitrary indices.

Comment: Badly implemented set?

Comment: Closed hash table with degenerate hash function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like just an array.

In many / most programming languages, you can set values in an array to uninitialized (e.g. null values in Java, C++, C#, C) (without shifting other values around).

Perhaps you also want a set to keep track of the free indices, which would result in expected `O(1)` (hash table-based) or `O(log n)` (binary search tree-based), as opposed to `O(n)`, for the `find-free-index` or `insert` operation.

Perhaps every person should also keep track of his / her own index if you want to efficiently (`O(1)`) remove a person without an index.